# Overriding GWT locale constants

Tags: gwt

GWT i18n module is missing a locale that i need "pt_BR". It fallbacks to the "pt" locale.

I think it's possible to add other locales if they are in the package `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr`. Does the i18n module support this by configuration instead of convention?

I also need to change some constants in an already existing locale, again, i only see the possibility of override by monkey patching that locale implementation.

Does the GWT's i18n support these use cases (new locales and overrides) without the need to monkey patch current implementations?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind why you are getting "pt" when you select "pt_BR" is

```
/**
 * Add special aliases for a given locale.
 *
 * This includes things like choosing the default region for Chinese based on
 * the script, handling Norwegian language changes, and treating pt_BR as the
 * default pt type.
```

The above content is taken from the forum thread
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/QuLHId_hLVY

Comment: I understand that, but my question was about the following use cases: adding a non-existent locale (e.g. "pt_BR") or changing the constants for a given locale (e.g. "es"). For now i'm monkey patching the "es" constants and added a `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_pt_BR` implementation in my project. I wonder if there's a built-in way to extend the available locales.